# Option to change domain name not appearing in Google Search Console site settings

Tags: google, google-search-console, domains, change-address-tool

I want to tell Google that my address is changed from one domain to another

But I am not getting the option to change the address:

[image: Search Console Settings -- no change domain name]

Answer (score 1):

The change of address tool is not supported in the new GSC interface
If you go to the old interface:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home

access the relevant GSC Property in the list and then click the gear icon at icon at the upper right and it has the *Change of Address* option in the offered list of options

ref: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en